# Column Invalid in the Selected List

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this scalar function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Custom_SumKayakoMonthProfit]
    (@ClientId int, @KKId int, 
     @StartDate SmallDateTime, @EndDate SmallDatetime,
     @Month int)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Total INT

    SELECT      
        @Total = ((CAST(SUM(WorkedTimeInMinutes) AS FLOAT) / 60) * KayakoValue)
    FROM
        [VDBSERVER2012\SQLEXPRESS2014].PlaterITDB.dbo.KayakoTimeEntries
    INNER JOIN  
        ClientContract ON ClientId = @ClientId 
                       AND Workdate BETWEEN ClientContract.StartDt AND ClientContract.EndDt
    WHERE       
        OrganizationID = @KKId 
        AND WorkDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
        AND MONTH(WorkDate) = @Month

    RETURN @Total
END
```

Whenever I try to execute it to use it on a stored procedure, I get this error.

> Column 'ClientContract.KayakoValue' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: You've aggregated `WorkedTimeInMinutes`, but not `KayakoValue` - what end result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Basically, the total cost of the time spent, that is, WorkedTimeInMinutes * KayakoValue.

Comment: XQbert, I tried. xD Unless I'm doing something wrong, it gives me the same error.

Comment: You may looking for this `SELECT      @Total = ((CAST(SUM(WorkedTimeInMinutes*KayakoValue) AS FLOAT)/60) )`

Comment: @SusanaFrancisco `SUM(WorkedTimeInMinutes)` will return a single value whereas `KayakoValue` will return multiple values because it is not aggregated. In this case, the SQL Server engine will not know which value of `kayokoValue` to use. This is why you recieve the message

Comment: Found the mistake. Thank you everyone. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What don't you understand about the message?  You have an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY`.  Hence, *all* columns must be the arguments to aggregation functions.

I suspect that you intend:

```
SELECT @Total = CAST(SUM(WorkedTimeInMinutes * KayakoValue) AS FLOAT)/60
FROM [VDBSERVER2012\SQLEXPRESS2014].PlaterITDB.dbo.KayakoTimeEntries kte INNER JOIN
     ClientContract cc
     ON ClientId = @ClientId AND
        Workdate BETWEEN cc.StartDt AND cc.EndDt
WHERE OrganizationID = @KKId AND
      WorkDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND MONTH(WorkDate) = @Month
```

Note that you should learn to use table aliases and to qualify all column names.  This is a good practice for writing readable and maintainable code.

Comment: I understood the message, but multiplying the minutes with the value per hour didn't make sense to me. I forgot I was diving the total value afterwards, so it did make sense. I guess after so long looking at this all annoyed I couldn't get it, I stopped thinking. xD
Thank you. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'KayakoValue' in aggregate function like sum,count, . . . or in group by at the end .

`SELECT      @Total = ((CAST(SUM(WorkedTimeInMinutes) AS FLOAT)/60) * KayakoValue)
FROM        [VDBSERVER2012\SQLEXPRESS2014].PlaterITDB.dbo.KayakoTimeEntries
INNER JOIN  ClientContract ON ClientId = @ClientId AND Workdate BETWEEN ClientContract.StartDt AND ClientContract.EndDt
WHERE       OrganizationID = @KKId AND WorkDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND MONTH(WorkDate) = @Month
group by KayakoValue`

OR

`SELECT      @Total = ((CAST(SUM(WorkedTimeInMinutes * KayakoValue) AS FLOAT)/60))
FROM        [VDBSERVER2012\SQLEXPRESS2014].PlaterITDB.dbo.KayakoTimeEntries
INNER JOIN  ClientContract ON ClientId = @ClientId AND Workdate BETWEEN ClientContract.StartDt AND ClientContract.EndDt
WHERE       OrganizationID = @KKId AND WorkDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND MONTH(WorkDate) = @Month`